# Stop Babel compiling jsx code?

Tags: ecmascript-6, jsx, babeljs, babel-cli

Most information and answers deal with issues of babel not compiling into JSX. In my case, I use .jsx as a templating engine, so I want babel to compile .js files but not .jsx files. Still I want to copy the files to a build/dist folder.

My app structure is:

```
App/
├── dist/
├── styles/
│   ├── _main.scss
│   ├── _module.scss
│   └── index.scss
├── assets/
│   ├── index.css
│   └── image.jpg
├── views/
│   ├── main.jsx
│   └── component.jsx
├── server.js
├── Models.js
├── Schemas.js
└── package.json
```

I have tried

```
babel src -d dist --ignore styles,*.jsx --copy-files views --presets es2015
```

It does not seem to recognize views folder

```
babel src -d dist --ignore styles --copy-files --presets es2015
```

It does things correctly, but also compiles .jsx, which breaks the views.

I also thought about removing the babel-loader package, but not sure if that is overdoing it.

I can't think of more information that you may need to answer, but let me know if you want me to put the package.json or any other files.

#### Update

There seems to be some confusion surrounding `--ignore` and `--copy-files`. Some people expect ignore to override copy and others copy to override ignore. In my case the latter will be preferable.

https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/5052
https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/5176

Now, if I do this

```
babel src --out-dir dist --copy-files --ignore styles,*jsx  --presets es2015
```

It ignores .jsx files, but it doesn't copy them. It does ignore styles directory, which is correct. It seems that it is incapable of ignoring something it can transpile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`--copy-files` option](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/#copy-files) copies the files that weren't processed 'as is'. It doesn't accept which files they are like `--copy-files views`.

[`--ignore` option](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/#ignore-files) ignores files entirely, which is undesirable behaviour here.

The problem is that Babel processes .jsx files, not that it compiles JSX. Babel doesn't compile JSX syntax if `react` preset isn't specified, so it is perceived as syntax errors. This happens because it [processes .jsx files by default](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/#options). The solution is to override defaults with `--extensions` option:

```
babel src -d dist --extensions .js --copy-files --presets es2015
```

This should transpile all .js files from ES6 to ES5 and just copy everything else.

It should be mentioned that Babel is just a transpiler and may be not the right tool for complex file manipulation tasks. This is what dedicated automation tools like Grunt and Gulp are for.

Comment: That was perfect! I was so focused on compiling I didn't realize there was such an option to set extensions. Many thanks